# Magento 2: Set Category Limit in List

Tags: magento2, php, category

I'm listing out my categories on the homepage, but I only want to list out 7 categories on the homepage for now.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul class="category-list">
<?php
foreach($categories as $category):
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }

?>
<li class="category-item"><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
<?php if($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
             if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
             }
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
endif;
endforeach;
?>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'd also like to limit the child categories to only 3.  I know this is probably a simple php edit, but I'm currently stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to insert an iterator in both loops and break it at 7 and 3:

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul class="category-list">
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($categories as $category):
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
     if($i == 7){
        break; //break it at seven
     }
     $i++;

?>
<li class="category-item"><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
<?php if($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        $child_number = 0;
        foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
             if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
             }
             if($child_number == 3){
                break; //break it at 3 for children
             }
             $child_number++;
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
endif;
endforeach;
?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any function to limit only 4 sub categories collection?

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes

Comment: Yes, pls help me with code, how to limit to 6 only?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a more efficient way to achieve this?

What's the point in dragging all the category data from the database if you just want to display a couple of categories.

I'm trying to figure out the same thing, I have a store that could potentially have 100's of categories but I want to display 8 categories on the homepage.

So far I've found you can use the same method as you've suggested, but as you said, that doesn't seem to allow us to add a limit.

I've also tried using the categoryCollectionFactory, which does allow me to set a limit, but drags in the "Default Category", the top level category which I don't want. So now I need to figure out a way to ignore that.

I don't want to use PHP in my view to break out of a loop as suggested by Claudiu because it's super inefficient.